Error when using crx gate in quantum circuit
When I try to run a quantum circuit that has a crx gate in it, I get an error AerError: 'unknown instruction: crx'. Below is an example of the code that I am trying to run:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_aer import Aer
import numpy as np

circ = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
circ.crx(np.pi/2, 0,1)
circ.measure_all()

job = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator').run(circ)
job.result().get_counts()

Please help me with this.

You are getting unknown instruction error because qasm_simulator does not have crx gate in the list of its basis gates. Here is the list of all the instructions that qasm_simulator supports:
['save_statevector', 'mcrx', 'mcrz', 'x', 'cu1', 'z', 'initialize', 's', 'mcsx', 'qerror_loc', 'h', 'ry', 'save_state', 'delay', 'set_density_matrix', 'id', 'unitary', 'cy', 'rzz', 'set_stabilizer', 'cu3', 'rz', 'save_probabilities', 'mcx', 'diagonal', 'p', 'save_density_matrix', 'reset', 'sdg', 'mcry', 'csx', 'measure', 'ccx', 'mcy', 'mcphase', 'rx', 'ecr', 'save_stabilizer', 'y', 'cu', 'cx', 'mcr', 'mcswap', 'sx', 'save_amplitudes_sq', 'save_expval', 'u2', 'save_expval_var', 'save_statevector_dict', 'mcz', 'quantum_channel', 'cswap', 'cp', 'kraus', 'cz', 'swap', 'r', 'u3', 'mcp', 'roerror', 'save_probabilities_dict', 'mcu2', 'ryy', 'mcu', 'rxx', 'pauli', 'rzx', 'mcu1', 'sxdg', 'tdg', 'multiplexer', 'u', 'save_amplitudes', 'mcx_gray', 'mcu3', 't', 'cu2', 'set_statevector', 'u1']

To fix this issue you need to transpile your code before running it on qasm_simulator. This can be achieved as below:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_aer import Aer
import numpy as np
from qiskit import transpile

circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.crx(np.pi/2, 0, 1)
circ.measure_all()

backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')

# Transpiling your circuit
transpile_circ = transpile(circ, backend=backend)

job = backend.run(transpile_circ, shots=1024)
job.result().get_counts()

This code correctly runs and the result is {'00': 1024} (which makes sense because crx won't act on qubit 1 if the control qubit is in zero state).
